# Disease prediction based on genes

Tags: cross-validation

I am a biologist and I am dealing with biological function prediction.

I have a model that annotates "disease" function for genes in a genome based on a set of "disease" genes as input. 
    Note: all these input genes have only one annotation (disease).

Now, based on the fact that I want to explore whether I predict the "disease" genes correctly, I was thinking of two possible ways:

- I would like to see how the model performs if I input only a set of genes in training and not the 100%.
- I have also other "validation" data sets. Basically other data sets of disease genes (or supposed to be) for which I also want to test how many I predict correctly/whats the overlap. In this case I would leave the 100% of input genes to the model [?] for the prediction.

I have no experience in this. Would you please show me the possible ways to do this?

(from the simplest to the most elegant)?

Comment: You mention training data and a model, but it is not clear how you train your model. Please add some details. Also, there is a fairly generic approach of looping through training followed by validation followed by a shift in the model followed by more training and validation, etc. When the best model is finally found, it is trained on all of the training data and presented for testing.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. i just have one model and i want to estimate how good it is in predicting/recovering true biological information (in this case disease genes) based on other different sources of true positives (e.g. several datasets of true positive disease genes obtained by different molecular biology approaches). So i have nothing to compare it with, except to a set of predicted genes by a null model (just random genes).

Comment: Then just run the model on all of your data and score the result: $N_{correct}/(N_{correct}+N_{incorrect})$. Nothing to train. Nothing to validate. Just . . . *test*!

Comment: Thank you Peter! I think im wrong with the terminology, because i would call a "correct" prediction a "validated" prediction, is that wrong? Could you please point me to some paper/paragraph/definition to understand how should i write what i do in my analysis?

Comment: Yes, *validation* is reserved for model selection. I'll add that in the absence of 1) *model development* and 2) *selection* through (respectively) 1) *training* and 2) *validation,* your only analytical point of entry is in conditioning. That is, *what is it about certain genes that give lower/higher error rates?* This is a nontrivial analysis, and the community would benefit from whatever wisdom you learn. My favorite introduction to statistical learning is the Caltech book and you-tubed MOOC *Learning from Data* by Yaser Abu-Mustafa.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a summary of my comments as an official answer . . .

If you already have a model *selected* and *trained*, then just *test,* viz., run the model on all of your data and score the result. Your error rate $E$ will be

$$
E=\frac{N_{incorrect}}{N_{correct}+N_{incorrect}}.
$$.

The term *validation* is reserved for model selection. I'll add that in the absence of iterative 1) *model development* and 2) *selection* through (respectively) 1) *training* and 2) *validation*, your only analytical point of entry is in **conditioning**. That is, *what is it about certain genes that give lower/higher error rates?* This is a nontrivial analysis, and your community would benefit from whatever wisdom you learn.

My favorite introduction to statistical learning is the Caltech book and you-tubed MOOC *Learning from Data* by Yaser Abu-Mustafa, et al.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity! very useful!

Comment: Is there anything else you are looking for in the answer before you accept it? If this is sufficient, please accept the answer. (Green check mark on left.)